# List to regex including leading blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

my list

```
mylist = [apple, banana, grape]
```

```
df

text
I love banana
apple is delicious
I eat pineapple
hate whitegrape
```

To match things that contain a list in the text, proceeded as follows.

```
mylist = [f"(?i){re.escape(k.lower())}" for k in mylist]
extracted = df['text'].str.lower().str.findall(f'({"|".join(mylist)})').apply(set)
df['matching'] = extracted.str.join(',')
```

There was a problem with matching, but since there is no space in front of the list, the'apple' I am looking for is included in'pineapple', so it matches.

As another example, I'm looking for 'grape', but grapes are contained in whitegrape, so this is also counting.

How can I give a space at the beginning of each index in the list?

```
result above
text                 matching
I love banana        banana
apple is delicious   apple
I eat pineapple      apple
hate whitegrape      grape
```

result what I want

```
text                 matching
I love banana        banana
apple is delicious   apple
I eat pineapple  
hate whitegrape
```

Comment: `Ieatpineapple ` ...`Ilovebanana `, hard for this case

Comment: A word boundary (actually two) in the regex could maybe help: `\b` but some of the texts can't be recognized with them.

Comment: @YOBEN_S Would it be the same if there were spaces between text words? edit contents

Comment: @MichaelButscher Is it difficult to move even if a space is applied between words in a sentence? Please look at the modified contents as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `split` then

```
df.text.str.lower().str.split().apply(lambda x : [y for y in x if y in mylist]).str[0]
Out[227]: 
0    banana
1     apple
2       NaN
3       NaN
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Update with `str.findall`

```
df.text.str.lower().str.findall(r'\b({0})\b'.format('|'.join(mylist)))
Out[248]: 
0    [banana]
1     [apple]
2          []
3          []
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: @ybin then do the string findall

Comment: It might be good to add the `re.IGNORECASE` flag since the OP uses `str.lower`. @YOBEN_S

Comment: @MrNobody33 yes I used `df['text'].str.lower().str.findall(r'\b({0})\b'.format('|'.join(mylist))).apply(set)`

Comment: Sure @ybin, I know it, it was just a suggestion to avoid the usage of  `str.lower` and use the flags that `re` provides us. :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
 df.text.str.extract(f"(?i)\\b({'|'.join(mylist)})\\b")
        0
0  banana
1   apple
2     NaN
3     NaN
```

Of course, you could change `extract` to `findall` as per your example